# Python Plot X axis value

Tags: python, plot, label, x-axis

i got a data of year,month,day and value CSV
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9MYh.png)

then i try to convert the year,month and day into dataframe

```
WTS_clean['dateInt']=WTS_clean['Year'].astype(str) + WTS_clean['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)+ WTS_clean['Day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
WTS_clean['DateDD'] = pd.to_datetime(WTS_clean['dateInt'], format='%Y%m%d')
WTS_clean['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(WTS_clean.DateDD).dt.to_period('M')
```

Year                    int64
Month                   int64
Day                     int64
Value                  object
Value_float           float64
dateInt                object
DateDD         datetime64[ns]
YearMonth              object
dtype: object

Then i try to take the mean by each month

```
WTS_summary=WTS_clean.groupby(WTS_clean.YearMonth).agg({'Value_float':'mean'})
WTS_summary.columns = ['Average Temp'] 
WTS_summary.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlHdn.png)

and want to plot the graph

```
plt.figure()

plt.plot(WTS_summary.values, label='WTS Avg Temp', linewidth=1,alpha = 0.7,c='salmon')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC0dh.png)

The question is how the x axis will start from 0 instead of 2009-03,2009-04 etc ?

How to change the x axis back to the value of grouped dt-WTS_summary?

Thanks a lot